# Look up if Mail Server exists for list of emails

Tags: delphi, email

is there a simple way to look up if a domain has a MX record or not using Delphi? I have a list of emails that I wish to verify work, I want to check each of the domains and see if a MX server even exists.

Thanks.

Edit: The email addresses I have are all from bounced email messages of error code: 5.4.0. But too many servers don't follow any standards and 5.4.0 error code itself can mean too much. I don't want to just remove all the email addresses found with that error code erroraneously, so I figure a better way is to first check if the domain or mx record don't exist and remove those for sure.

Comment: Do bear in mind that (a) just because the domain has an MX record, it doesn't mean that the server(s) named will accept mail for the address you're interested in, and (b) the lack of an MX record does not mean mail to that address can't be delivered (most MTAs will fall back to attempting to deliver to the IP the domain resolves to.)

Comment: Wow this sounds like a question a spammer would ask. :-)

Comment: It's actually for a newsletter. But yeah, the premise is the same I guess.

Comment: I'm not convinced it's worth the trouble to attempt to figure out if a DNS failure is ephemeral or if the domain is really dead.  If your mailing system already has a way of tracking delivery failures and removing addresses after *n* failures, continue using that.  Otherwise, that might be a more fruitful endeavor.

Comment: There are legitimate situations where mail checking can be justified. At least partial checking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is actually good to have an e-mail checker. If nothing else you can clean you e-mail base and avoid sending over and over to non existing mails. Or you can use it as means of verifying user mails when they sign on to your application.

Here is a part of the code in my mail checking class.

```
procedure TMailValidator.ResolveEmailAddress(const Address: TEMailAddress; const DNSServer: string);
var
  I: Integer;
  MXEmpty: Boolean;
  DomainName: string;
  DNSResolver: TIdDNSResolver;
begin
  DNSResolver := TIdDNSResolver.Create(nil);
  try
    DomainName := StrAfter('@', string(Address));
    MXEmpty := True;

    DNSResolver.Host := DNSServer;
    {$IFNDEF IT_UseIndy9}
      DNSResolver.QueryType := [qtMx];
    {$ELSE}
      DNSResolver.QueryRecords := [qtMx];
    {$ENDIF}  // IT_UseIndy9
    try
      {$IFNDEF IT_UseIndy9}
        DNSResolver.WaitingTime := FDNSResolveTimeout;
      {$ELSE}
        DNSResolver.ReceiveTimeout := FDNSResolveTimeout;
      {$ENDIF}  // IT_UseIndy10
      DNSResolver.Resolve(DomainName);

      for I := 0 to DNSResolver.QueryResult.Count - 1 do
      begin
        if DNSResolver.QueryResult[I].RecType = qtMX then
        begin
          MXEmpty := False;
          CheckEmailAddress(Address, TMXRecord(DNSResolver.QueryResult[I]).ExchangeServer);

          // were we successfull
          if CheckSMTPExitErrorCode then
            Exit;
        end;
      end;

      // check for servers flag
      if FFoundMailServer then
      begin
        SendLogMessage(Format('Address "%s" is not valid on domain "%s"', [Address, DNSServer]));
        SetLastError(cUserErrorCodeBase + 5);
      end
      else
      begin
        if MXEmpty then
        begin
          SendLogMessage(Format('No valid mail(MX) server could be found for domain "%s"', [DomainName]));
          CheckEmailAddress(Address, DomainName);
        end
        else
        begin
          SendLogMessage(Format('Mail server did not respond on domain "%s"', [DomainName]));
          SetLastError(cUserErrorCodeBase + 3);
        end;
      end;
    except
      on E: Exception do
      begin
        SendLogMessage(Format('Address "%s" validation failed for domain "%s": %s', [Address,
                                                                                     DomainName,
                                                                                     E.Message]));
        SetLastError(cUserErrorCodeBase + 4, E.Message);
      end;
    end;
  finally
    DNSResolver.Free;
  end;
end;


procedure TMailValidator.CheckEmailAddress(const Address: TEMailAddress; const MailServer: string);
var
  SMTP: TIdSMTP;
begin
  SendLogMessage(Format('Validating address "%s" on server "%s"', [Address, MailServer]));

  if (FCheckStep = csAddress) or (FCheckStep = csDomain) then
  begin
    // finish if flags in [FLAG_CheckLocal, FLAG_CheckDomain]
    SendLogMessage(Format('Address "%s" successfuly validated.', [Address]));
    Exit;
  end;

  SMTP := TIdSMTP.Create(nil);
  try
    FCurrentStep := csMailBox;
    try
      SMTP.ReadTimeout := FSMTPReadTimeout;
      {$IFNDEF IT_UseIndy9}
        SMTP.AuthType := satNone;
      {$ELSE}
        SMTP.AuthenticationType := atNone;
      {$ENDIF}  // IT_UseIndy9
      SMTP.Host := MailServer;
      SMTP.Port := 25;

      SMTP.Connect;
      try
        FFoundMailServer := True;

        try
          SMTP.SendCmd('Helo ' + FQueryingServer, 250 );
          SMTP.SendCmd('Rset');
          SMTP.SendCmd('Mail from:<' + string(Address) + '>', 250);
          SMTP.SendCmd('RCPT to:<' + string(Address) + '>', [250, 251] );

          SendLogMessage(Format('Address "%s" successfuly validated on server "%s".', [FEMailAddress,
                                                                                       MailServer]));
        except
          on E: Exception do
          begin
            SendLogMessage(Format('Address "%s" validation failed on server "%s": %s', [Address,
                                                                                        MailServer,
                                                                                        E.Message]));
            SetLastError(SMTP.LastCmdResult.NumericCode, E.Message);
            Exit;
          end;
        end
      finally
        SMTP.Disconnect;
      end;
    except
      // handle all other exceptions
      on E: Exception do
      begin
        SendLogMessage(Format('CheckMail [%s] : Failure (Server) "%s" [%s]', [Address,
                                                                              MailServer,
                                                                              E.Message]));
        SetLastError(Max(cUserErrorCodeBase + 6, SMTP.LastCmdResult.NumericCode), E.Message);
      end;
    end;
  finally
    SMTP.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Basically you do it in three steps:

1. Check the mail syntax.
2. Check the domain and validate MX server
3. Validate the user mailbox

Comment: Successfully completing step #3 doesn't mean that the mailbox is valid, it simply means that the mail server may accept mail for that address.  The mail server may reject the message after sending data, or may happily accept the message from you before turning around and deleting it.

Comment: Also, the particularly nitpicky might not like you using exceptions for common error control/code flow purposes.  Bad email addresses, downed hosts, full mailboxes, etc. aren't *exceptional* cases.  :-)  (I'm not going to claim complete innocence of that particular code smell myself though.)

Comment: I am not raising exceptions, only setting last error codes. At the end you only check the error code of the whole process. Also I have to catch the Indy exceptions, because Indy uses exceptions to handle the flow of code. I don't like that either. I am only doing what Windows API does

Answer (score 2):

You can use the windows [DnsQuery](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682016%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) API to check the MX records for a given server name. Unfortunately I didn't find a proper Delphi translation for the headers, so I made a partial (but workable) translation myself. It only supports MX and IpV4 A records, nothing else. Adding support for IpV6 address should be trivial.

Here's my translation, including a simple `ServerHasMxRecords(const ServerName:string):Boolean` function that returns `True` if any MX records are found:

```
unit DnsMxCheck;

interface

uses Windows, Classes;

type
  DNS_STATUS = Integer;
  IP4_ADDRESS = DWORD;

  _DNS_RECORD_FLAGS = packed record
     case Boolean of
     True: (DW: DWORD);
     False: (DNS_RECORD_FLAGS: DWORD);
   end;

   DNS_A_DATA = packed record
     case Boolean of
       True: (IpAddress: IP4_ADDRESS);
       False: (Bytes:array[0..3] of Byte);
   end;

   DNS_MX_DATA = packed record
     pNameExchange: PWChar;
     wPreference: Word;
     Pad: Word;
   end;

   _DNS_RECORD_DATA_UNION = packed record
     case Integer of
       0: (A: DNS_A_DATA);
       1: (MX1, MX2, AFSDB1, AFSDB2, RT1, RT2: DNS_MX_DATA);
       999: (Filler: array[0..1024] of Byte); // I have no idea what the true size of the record shoud be!
   end;

   PDNS_RECORD = ^DNS_RECORD;
   DNS_RECORD = packed record
     NextRecord: PDNS_RECORD;
     pName: PWChar;
     wType: Word;
     wDataLength: Word;
     Flags: _DNS_RECORD_FLAGS;
     dwTtl: DWORD;
     dwReserved: DWORD;
     Data: _DNS_RECORD_DATA_UNION;
   end;

const DNS_TYPE_A =  $0001;
      DNS_TYPE_MX   = $000f;

function DnsQuery_W(lpstrName: PWChar; wType: Word; Options: DWORD; pExtra: Pointer; out ppQueryResultsSet: PDNS_RECORD; pReserved: Pointer): DNS_STATUS;stdcall;external 'dnsapi.dll';

function ServerHasMxRecords(const ServerName:string):Boolean;

implementation

function ServerHasMxRecords(const ServerName:string):Boolean;
var DNS_REC: PDNS_RECORD;
begin
  if DnsQuery_W(PWChar(ServerName), DNS_TYPE_MX, 0, nil, DNS_REC, nil) = 0 then
  begin
    while Assigned(DNS_REC) do
    begin
      if DNS_REC.wType = DNS_TYPE_MX then
      begin
        Exit(True);
      end;
      DNS_REC := DNS_REC.NextRecord;
    end;
  end;
  Result := False;
end;

end.
```

Answer (score 1):

The only way to check if you can deliver an email is to actually deliver it, and check the zillion ways you can get a bounce response.

Comment: No, you do not actually send data. You just check for the recipient.

Comment: Actually: you have to send data, the check for recipient sometimes returns OK while actually sending does work.

Comment: I didn't know that. But it seems actually sending the data would be overdoing it :) There is no 100% way to confirm an email anyway short of actually sending an email and getting a reply :)

Comment: @Runner: my point exactly :) Bonus chatter: when you redeliver the same message, you might get a different result.